Short horror/sci-fi story - spoken words turn into a solid, indestructible material
I saw this online, and I think it was an older public domain work (maybe on Gutenberg?) rather something modern like a creepypasta, but I'm not entirely sure. It's not The Memetic Symbol, though the concept is kind of similar.
The premise: one day, every word people speak manifests as a solid object made of a black, indestructible material. These objects are very heavy/cumbersome to move, so people have to work around them, while trying to find non-verbal or non-vocal ways to communicate. I don't remember anything else about the plot or ending, or if the phenomenon was ever explained.

I started to answer and OMG he died four days ago. Rest in peace, Mr. Zebrowski.

RIP George Zebrowski. Please provide the answer anyway.

What happened, did typing his name cause an indestructible block to appear on top of your computer??

Feel free to accept your own answer when you are able.

Following on Dragan and jo1storm's comments above, I managed to find the story: The Word Sweep by George Zebrowski. It's a little different than what I remembered, but definitely the same premise:

He went into the bedroom and lay down. When he tried, he could almost remember the time when words did not materialize. He must have been four or five when it happened for the first time. He remembered wafer-thin objects, letters joined together in as many differing styles as there were speakers.


At first it had been a novelty, then a perpetual snowstorm. Cities had to clean up after a daily disaster, three hundred and sixty-five days a year, trucking the words to incinerators and landfills. The words would burn only at high temperatures, and even then they would give off a toxic gas which had to be contained. There had been a government project to find a use for the gas, but it took too much energy for the burning to make it worthwhile; later the gas was found to be useless.


Psychiatric treatment came to a halt, then shifted to computer printout and nonverbal therapies. Movies had gone back to silent and subtitled versions; only the very rich could afford to truck away the refuse after each talkie showing. Opera was performed in mime and music-only reductions....

